# If relation $R^2$ is symmetric, R does not need to be symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was checking a question that said the following

> If $R^2$ is symmetric, does that mean that R is symmetric?

This being R a relation on the set $A$.

What I thought the proof would be is:

$$aR^2c \land cR^2a$$
This because $R^2$ is symmetric.

From the definition of $R^2$:

$$aRb \land bRc \iff aR^2c$$
$$bRa \land cRb \iff cR^2a$$

Here we can see that R is symmetric
$$aRb \land bRa$$
$$bRc \land cRb$$

---

However... this is not true... it does not mean that R is symmetric (I can give an example).

What did I miss in my proof?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $R^2$ being symmetric does **not** mean that $aR^2c\land cR^2a$ for arbitrary $a,c\in A$. It means that **if** $aR^2c$, **then** $cR^2a$. Equivalently, it means that if $a,c\in A$, then **either** $aR^2c\land cR^2a$, **or** $a\not R^2c\land c\not R^2a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks! you can post it as an answer

Comment: Done! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2$ being symmetric does **not** mean that $aR^2c\land cR^2a$ for arbitrary $a,c\in A$. It means that **if** $aR^2c$, **then** $cR^2a$. Equivalently, it means that if $a,c\in A$, then **either** $aR^2c\land cR^2a$, **or** $a\not R^2c\land c\not R^2a$.